# Angular Highcharts: this.options.series[0].setData() is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, highcharts

I am using Highcharts with Angular.  While attempting to setData and update I encountered the following errors:

> ERROR TypeError: self.options.series[0].data[0].update is not a function
>
> ERROR TypeError: self.options.series[0].data[0].setData is not a function

Function:

```
options: any;

ngAfterViewInit() {

  var dataOne = [{
    name: 'Living Room',
      y: 110
    }, {
      name: 'Entryway',
      y: 36
    }, {
      name: 'Kitchen',
      y: 70
  }];

  this.options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
    },
    series: [{
      "colorByPoint": true,
      data: [{
        y: 100,
        name: 'Living Room',
      }, {
        y: 34,
        name: 'Entryway',
      }, {
        y: 67,
        name: 'Kitchen',
      }]
    }]
  } // end this.options

  self = this;
  jQuery('#button1').click(function () {
      //this.options.series[0].setData(dataOne); // same error
      self.options.series[0].setData(dataOne);
    });

  var y = 30;
  jQuery('#button2').click(function () {
      y += 10;
      //this.options.series[0].data[0].update(y); // same error 
      self.options.series[0].data[0].update(y)
    });

} //end ngAfterViewInit
```

When I do `console.log(self.options.series[0])` I get `{colorByPoint: true, data: Array(3)}`

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/1248/) to show the intended behaviors

I exhausted StackOverflow and Google but couldn't find any question related to my errors.

Comment: `update` can be performed on point object if you refer to it **after the chart is created** using the given path: `chart.series[0].points[0]` (where `chart` is a result of `Highcharts.chart` call). Currently you're trying to call `update` on **options** object **before the chart is created** - it is incorrect. Here's a simple demo that shows how to update the point correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fuqL72j6/

Comment: I suspected that missing Highcharts.chart was the problem and you confirmed it.  I have to use `options` instead of `chart` because I couldn't get `var chart = Highcharts.chart` to work with Angular no matter what I do.

Comment: Have you tried to use official **Highcharts wrapper for Angular**?: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular